# Vue multiple templates for a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm running into an issue cause by Vue's single root element for component limitation. In my example below I'm trying to insert a component into both a table and a list and depending on the view selected, show one or the other, however the way I'm handling this breaks my layout.

Parent component:

```
<ul v-show="view === 'thumb'>
  <component v-for="stuff in array" :view="view"></component
</ul>
<table v-show="view === 'table'>
  <component v-for="stuff in array" :view="view"></component>
</table>
```

Child component now needs it's root element to be **EITHER** `<tr>` or `<li>` in order not to break the layout, depending on the `view`. Here's the problem:

1) Vue component template must have only one root element.

2) `<template>`, which is ignored in a template and not rendered, cannot be used as the root element.

3) There's a lot of code in the subcomponent, and mostly it's the same logic regardless of the view selected, so the only real difference is the layout.

4) `<ul>`'s can be substituted for `<div>`'s, but `<table>`'s have to stay.

The only solution I can think of is to create two separate components, one for each view. To keep as KISS and DRY as possible, create a separate class that handles the logic and each component just delegates everything to that class instance.

Perhaps there's an easier way of using two different templates and a single logic part in Vue?

Laravel has pushing and stacking in blades to propagate HTML to parent blades. Maybe there's something similiar in Vue?

Perhaps someone can think of a better solution? Perhaps I'm fixed on a stupid idea and can't see an easy workaround?

Comment: Why not use `<component :is="view === 'thumb' ? 'ul' : 'table'">`?

Comment: @Li357 Where can I find information about the `:is` property? Haven't seen it before and can't seem to be able to find info in the documentation.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#component

Comment: Thank you. What worked for me was to use `:is` in the child component's root element to have it be a row or a list element depending on the view variable and conditionally render the contents with normal `v-if` inside.